# Gallery thumbnails not showing full title - NextGEN Gallery Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, title, nextgen-gallery

I am using the NextGen Gallery plugin on my wordpress site. My problem is that the thumbnails to my galleries won't show their full titles, but only the first parts. If the title to a gallery was "The full title", it would only show "The full..." under the thumbnail. Like if it wasn't enough space for the full title. This makes it very difficult to find the photos you are looking for. Is there some way to show the full title? Here is a link to my site so you can see: http://tornaia.com/bilder/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. By changing the shortcode from *{[album id=1]* to *[album id=1 template=extend]*, the album looks better (in my opinion) and all the text is showing. So that works for me :)